# Induction Proof: If $B \subseteq A$, then $|B| \leq |A|$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, induction

Prove by induction that if $A$ is a finite set and $B$ is a subset of $A$, then $|B|≤ |A|$.

I can prove the base case with $n=0$ easily, but am stuck as to how to proceed from there.

Comment: What does $n$ represent?

Comment: The cardinality of A

Comment: Read this famous "false proof" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color  You can copy much of the structure of the proof, just don't make the same mistake between the base case and the inductive step.

Comment: So you want to prove it only for finite sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, via the inductive hypothesis, that if $|A| = k$ and $B \subseteq A$, then $|B| \leq |A|$.

We want to show that if $|A| = k+1$ and $B \subseteq A$, then $|B| \leq |A|$.

Choose any element $x \in B$ (so $x$ also belongs to $A$). The cardinality of the set $A \setminus \{x\}$ is $k$ and $B \setminus \{x\}$ is a subset of $A \setminus \{x\}$, so we conclude $|B \setminus \{x\}| \leq |A \setminus \{x\}|$ by the inductive hypothesis. Now,
\begin{align*}
|B| &= |B \setminus \{x\}| + 1\\
&\leq |A \setminus \{x\}| + 1\\
&= |A|.
\end{align*}

Comment: I really have no idea, it's something assigned that wasn't taught and Im having a hard time teaching it to myself having never seen a similar example.